# ajaxupload jeditable and zend framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, jeditable

I am trying to use jeditable with ajaxupload, you can see a demo [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html). I am using this plugin in a zend view file as follows:

JS CODE

```
$(".ajaxupload").editable("<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/inside/students/update-student'); ?>", {
            indicator : "<img src='<?php echo $this->baseUrl('img/indicator.gif'); ?>'>",
            type      : 'ajaxupload',
            submit    : 'Upload',
            cancel    : 'Cancel',
            tooltip   : "Click to upload..."
        });
```

HTML CODE

```
<img class="left-floating-image=" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl($this->user['img_path']); ?>" />
        <p id="img_path" class="ajaxupload">Upload</p>
```

My PHP code in the zend controller:

```
public function updateStudentAction() {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $params = $this->_request->getParams();
            Zend_Debug::dump($params);
            $field = $params['id'];
            $value = $params['value'];
//            $userID = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id;
//
//            $userModel = new Application_Model_Users();
//            $userModel->update(array($field => $value), "id = $userID");
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that when i dump the POST vars i don't get the posted variable. I only get this:

```
array(3) {
  ["module"] => string(6) "inside"
  ["controller"] => string(8) "students"
  ["action"] => string(14) "update-student"
}
```

And 2 errors saying that there is no index 'id' or 'value'. I checked what is being sent to the server using Tamper Data plugin for firefox. Here is the output:

```
21:46:09.886[634ms][total 634ms] Status: 200[OK]
POST http://localhost/industrial/public/inside/students/update-student Load Flags[LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI  LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI  ] Content Size[540] Mime Type[text/html]
   Request Headers:
      Host[localhost]
      User-Agent[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12]
      Accept[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]
      Accept-Language[en-us,en;q=0.5]
      Accept-Encoding[gzip,deflate]
      Accept-Charset[ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7]
      Keep-Alive[115]
      Connection[keep-alive]
      Referer[http://localhost/industrial/public/inside/students]
      Cookie[PHPSESSID=dufubvhd6bihqd4jk5q655bap3]
   Post Data:
      POST_DATA[-----------------------------215452871217546
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value"; filename="btn_companies.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG
```

How can i get the file that is being sent if Zend doesn't get the POST_DATA? Once this is solved i need to make this method take decisions on the type of data that is being submitted (text or files).

Answer (score 0):

first of: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/perm.php?a=zend-framework-jeditable 
Then I'm still not quite sure but this is what i learnt last week:

> Hi,
>
> You can not read from a file input
>   field with jQuery/JavaScript, this is
>   due to js security restrictions. If I
>   remember correctly any read from a
>   file input element will return an
>   empty string.
>
> The $form->isValidPartial() method
>   will not perform the validation as
>   request param mailattcht is empty.
>
> Also you can not perform a file upload
>   through AJAX if this was your ultimate
>   intention.
>
> Kind regards
>
> Garry

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=11833